# I want a famous application of comprehensive grobner basis w.r.t. lex order and w.r.t. some conditions on parametric coefficients.

Tags: groebner-basis

Let $I$ be an parametric polynomial ideal in $K[a_1,\cdots,a_m][x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ where $a_1,\cdots,a_m$ is a sequence of parameters and $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ is a sequence of variables. Is there any famous example or application which in it we must compute the reduced Groebner basis of $I$  w.r.t. lex ordering and w.r.t. some conditions on parameters?

Comment: Depends on what you consider as "famous". But yes, there are "famous" examples, e.g., for the Auslander conjecture.

Comment: Your problem translated to a parametric polynomial ideal? Is there any conditions on parameters?

Comment: Yes, there is. In particular, one wants to find the "important" conditions on the parameters.

Comment: Could you please send it for me and determine the variables and parameters?